# Parsing iCalendar with custom fields via Ruby/Rails rake task

Tags: ruby, rake, icalendar, data-import

I have a rake task setup that imports events from an [iCal file](http://www.trumba.com/calendars/smithsonian-events.ics) using the iCalendar gem.  The iCal also contains several custom fields in addition to the standard .ics fields.  Is it possible to import those values as well?

Lines like this in the iCal file I can handle with no problem:

```
DESCRIPTION:The lions and tigers are on exhibit.
```

The issue arises for lines like this:

```
X-TRUMBA-CUSTOMFIELD;NAME="Event Location";ID=10831;TYPE=SingleLine:Lower Level\, 
across from the Stars and Stripes Cafe
```

How would I refer to the custom "Event Location" field?

Here's the code that I have thus far:

```
desc "Import events from Smithsonian"
task :smithsonian => :environment do
  url = "http://www.trumba.com/calendars/smithsonian-events.ics"
  cals = Icalendar.parse(open(url))
  cal = cals.first

  cal.events.each do |event|
    e = TempEvent.find_or_create_by_name(
          :name         => event.summary.to_s,
          :description  => event.description.to_s,
          :starts_at    => event.dtstart.to_s,
          :ends_at      => event.dtend.to_s,
          :tag_list     => event.categories,
          :url          => event.url,
          :facebook_url => "https://www.facebook.com/Smithsonian",
          :twitter_url  => "https://twitter.com/smithsonian",
          :venue_name   => "Smithsonian",
          :external_id  => event.uid.to_s,
          :source       => "Smithsonian iCal import",
          :published    => true)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `icalendar` gem.
Assuming there is an attribute of this type

> ORGANIZER;CN=abc:MAILTO:abc@gmail.com

To access the parameter values
read and parse the ical file.

`cal = Icalendar.parse(cal_file).first`

`event = cal.events.first`

Now, event.organizer gives me a uri.

To access CN value use,

`event.organizer.ical_params["CN"][0]`